# Modal windows using ASP.NET MVC and JQuery, iframe vs inline?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-plugins

I have one main view that has about ten links on it. Each link currently opens a modal window using an iframe (colorbox plugin) which loads another view into the iframe modal window. Each one of these forms are hooked up to the jquery validate and jquery form plugins.

Once a form is submitted using the jquery form plugin a method on the parent page is called from the modal window to make some updates on the main view page.

This all works just fine but I am wondering if there is a better way to accomplish this without iframes? I have seen examples where the modal window is loaded as a partial in the main view and displayed inline. This might be great for one or two modal windows but I have about ten.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check out jQuery.UI Dialog
http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Answer (score 0):

I use jquery fancybox for things like this [www.fancybox.net](http://www.fancybox.net)